# MariaDB won't start on FreeBSD 10

Tags: mysql, freebsd, mariadb

I installed MariaDB on my home server with FreeBSD 10, but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
141217 18:30:41 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /db/mysql
141217 18:30:41 [ERROR] mysqld: File './mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13     "Permission denied")
141217 18:30:41 [ERROR] Aborting

141217 18:30:41 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

141217 18:30:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /db/mysql/computername.pid ended
```

But I think that the permissions are right

```
    root@computer /db/mysql # ls -l
    total 111780
    -rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql     16384 Dec 17 18:00 aria_log.00000001
    -rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql        52 Dec 17 18:00 aria_log_control
    -rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql  50331648 Dec 17 18:00 ib_logfile0
    -rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql  50331648 Dec 17 18:00 ib_logfile1
    -rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql  12582912 Dec 17 18:00 ibdata1
    -rw-r-----  1 mysql  mysql      2280 Dec 17 18:30 _computername_
    drwx------  2 mysql  mysql        89 Dec 17 18:00 mysql/
    -rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql     69110 Dec 17 18:00 mysql-bin.000001
    -rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql    977605 Dec 17 18:00 mysql-bin.000002
    -rwxrwxrwx  1 mysql  mysql        48 Dec 17 18:22 mysql-bin.index*
    -rw-rw----  1 mysql  mysql         9 Dec 17 18:00 mysql-bin.state
    drwx------  2 mysql  mysql        55 Dec 17 18:00 performance_schema/
    drwx------  2 mysql  mysql         2 Dec 17 18:00 test/
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Does mysqld run as user mysql? Is "." really "/db/mysql"? (e.g. put some debug output in the script) Can you try the same under the id of user mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the `/db/mysql` directory is user **and group** readable and writable by `mysql:mysql`.

Possibly run as root `chmod ug+rw /db/mysql`.